# Is it right to flag questions for migration to tor.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, migration, flagging, stackexchange

This site is still in early beta phase so I am wondering if it is right to flag questions on other Stack Exchange sites for migration to tor.stackexchange.com?

Is it right both for old questions which were asked/active before tor.stackexchange.com started to exist and new questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent question; I asked around on the super-top-secret moderators chat from which you never quote ever under any circumstances and found this:

> Migrations to/from beta sites - particularly when they're still *very*
>   young - are discouraged

—[Shog9](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3435/shog9) (thanks for letting me quote you Shog9)

For a good explanation by Tim of why this is a bad idea, check out [this meta question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5779/can-we-please-add-http-sqa-stackexchange-com-as-a-migration-target/5780#5780) on Programmers.SE.

Comment: That said, we have had a couple of questions migrated over. So it's not a hard-and-fast rule. They just have to be a really really good fit.